# D3 layout with draggable nodes

Tags: d3.js

I have created a forced layout graph. it is working fine.

Now I need to make the blocks draggable such that, even after dragging the block it should not affect the other blocks as shown in [this](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html) example.

Here's what I tried:

```
    d3.json("links.json", function(error, links) {

    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});

    });

    var width = 1000,
        height = 700;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .gravity(0.01) 
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(200)
        .charge(-600)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["forward","back"]) //use .data(["forward","back","front"]) for different types of data
      .enter().append("marker")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 100)
        .attr("refY", 1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-4L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });



    var rect = svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
        .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", -20)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("width", function(d) { return (d.weight*40);  })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return (d.weight*20); })
        .call(force.drag).on("mouseover", fade(.1))
        .on("mouseout", fade(1));;

    force.drag().on('drag', fade(.1));

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
        .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", ".41em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
     rect.attr("transform", transform);
      path.attr("d", linkLine);

      text.attr("transform", transform); 
    }

    function transform(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And data in links.json file is

```
  [{"source": "Delhi", "target": "Mangalore", "type": "forward"},
         {"source": "Mangalore", "target": "Delhi", "type": "back"},
          {"source": "Delhi", "target": "Yashvanthpur", "type": "back"},
          {"source": "Mangalore", "target": "Rome", "type": "forward"},
          {"source": "Delhi", "target": "Mysore", "type": "forward"},

          {"source": "Chandigarh", "target": "Vellore", "type": "forward"},
          {"source": "Chandigarh", "target": "Mangalore", "type": "forward"},
          {"source": "Delhi", "target": "Nagpur", "type": "forward"}

        ]
```

Are there any methods so that, I will not get any movements in the other nodes, even though I drag some node in the graph?

Is there any separate method to accomplish that?

Comment: post your code as a working fiddle or snippet pls

Comment: I am not able to send fiddle, but my code works something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/Lyr52v8w/

Comment: Did you just edit this 7 month old question in order to ask a different new one?

Comment: nope. This is the same question, with improved formatting.

Comment: Replacing the useful code in a question by an external link is not the same as improved formatting. If you want to improve formatting do it here. Questions which consists of external links only are in danger of decaying with the availability of the linked resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property `fixed` to `true` for each node when force simulations are stopped.

```
force.on('end', function(d) {
    links.forEach(function(l) {
      l.source.fixed = true;
      l.target.fixed = true;
    })
  });
```

```js
var links = [{
    "source": "Delhi",
    "target": "Mangalore",
    "type": "forward"
  },
  {
    "source": "Mangalore",
    "target": "Delhi",
    "type": "back"
  },
  {
    "source": "Delhi",
    "target": "Yashvanthpur",
    "type": "back"
  },
  {
    "source": "Mangalore",
    "target": "Rome",
    "type": "forward"
  },
  {
    "source": "Delhi",
    "target": "Mysore",
    "type": "forward"
  },

  {
    "source": "Chandigarh",
    "target": "Vellore",
    "type": "forward"
  },
  {
    "source": "Chandigarh",
    "target": "Mangalore",
    "type": "forward"
  },
  {
    "source": "Delhi",
    "target": "Nagpur",
    "type": "forward"
  }

];
var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
    name: link.source
  });
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
    name: link.target
  });

});

var width = 1000,
  height = 700;

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .gravity(0.01)
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(200)
  .charge(-600)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start()
  
force.on('end', function(d) {
    links.forEach(function(l) {
      l.source.fixed = true;
      l.target.fixed = true;
    })
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["forward", "back"]) //use .data(["forward","back","front"]) for different types of data
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 100)
  .attr("refY", 1.5)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-4L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
  .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "link " + d.type;
  })
  .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
    return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
  });



var rect = svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", -20)
  .attr("y", -20)
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return (d.weight * 40);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return (d.weight * 20);
  })
  .call(force.drag).on("mouseover", fade(.1))
  .on("mouseout", fade(1));;

force.drag().on('drag', fade(.1));

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d){ return -20+(d.weight * 20) })
  .attr("y", function(d){ return -20+(d.weight * 20)/2 })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  rect.attr("transform", transform);
  path.attr("d", linkLine);

  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

var linkedByIndex = {};

links.forEach(function(d) {
  linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
  return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] ||
    linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] ||
    a.index == b.index;
};

function linkLine(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;

  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

// For fade-in and fade-out effect
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(d) {
    rect.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
      thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
      this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
      return thisOpacity;
    });

    rect.style("stroke-opacity", opacity)
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
      });
  };
};
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#forward {
  fill: green;
}

#back {
  fill: red;
}

<!-- #back {
  fill: green;
}

-->.link.forward {
  stroke: green;
}

.link.back {
  stroke: green;
}

rect {
  fill: #a5b0ed;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway, to make graph not to move when loaded?